# Where is .bashrc or .bash_profile on OpenSuse linux?

Tags: bash, rvm, opensuse

I'm trying to install rvm, and it wants me to edit my .bashrc or .bash_profile files to include rvm...  But I can't FIND these files anywhere. A quick google search shows that they might not exist until I make them (weird), but I can't see any reference to WHERE I should make them.

EDIT:  Okay, it from one of the responses, it looks like I need to put them in my /home directory...and I can use ls -la to see if they are really there or not (they are not), but when I make the files, and put:

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in them, as instructed by rvm, even when I make a new shell, I still can't type "rvm" and get anywhere.

Does that mean the files are in the wrong place, or that I made them wrong, or that the thing I put in them is wrong....I don't even know where to begin...

I made the files (as root), by typing "vi .bashrc" and vi ".bash_profile"...  but when I look at them, the files seem to be named just "bashrc" and "bash_profile".  SO, I did "mv bashrc .bashrc" and that seemed to do the trick AND hid them...but...I still can't type "rvm" in a new shell...

Edit:  When I type

$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

I got a "permission denied" error, even while root. So I went there, and the "rvm" file doesn't have executable permissions, for whatever reason... SO I set it to be executable. So now I don't get that error anymore...but I ALSO still can't run RVM, even in a new shell.

SOLUTION:

I was completely mis-understanding what "root of your home directory" meant, and was trying to put them in the directory named "home". INSTEAD, I was supposed to put them in the place where $HOME was pointing to.  Now that the files are in the right place (and .bashrc at least already existed, so i just edited it), everything is working perfectly

Comment: Are you installing this as root or as a regular user? What is the exact command line you are running?

Comment: Should be as a regular user.  I'm following the documentation exactly, and ran:  bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )

Comment: Are you creating the `.bashrc` file in `/home` or `/home/username`? It should be the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out just before you posted, I was doing it in /home, not /home/username.  Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should make them in the root of your home directory, if they don't exist already.

Comment: ...Okay. So. Um. I've made the empty files, and copied and pasted " [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm""  into them...but...I'm still not able to use the command "rvm", even in a new shell

Comment: strange, if you have already downloaded it, and the path $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm exists it should work. Try restart the shell.

Comment: Even after fully restarting my machine, I still do not see the command.  I have also confirmed that the path exists....but weirdly, I have "permission denied" when I confirm that it exists (even as root). Not sure what is going on...Wait, maybe it was trying to run it as a program, and it's not executable?

Comment: @Jenny: Is the executable bit set?

Comment: Now it is (made an edit to my original post to refelct this), but all that does is get rid of the "permission denied" problem...still can't actually run rvm

Answer (score 10):

The `.` in front of the filename indicates that they are hidden files, so execute `ls -la` to see if they exist.

[A Sample .bashrc File](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html)
[Sample .bash_profile](http://sweatte.wordpress.com/syntax/unix-shell-command-tips/sample-bash_profile/)

[bashrc vs. bash_profile](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bashrc-vs-bash_profile-87412/)

Answer (score 2):

You say you created the files as root, but are you running the command as root? While logged in as the user which will attempt to use this `rvm` command try running the line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && echo exists || echo not there
```

directly from your shell. If it echo's "not there" then the location specified does not exist and that's your problem.

If it says "exists" then the contents of the directory may not be what is expected.

But, is it necessary to install RVM manually this way? Isn't there something available from your distribution's package manager that will take care of this for you?

Comment: Even as root, I am not seeing rvm, specifically, I get: sudo: rvm: command not found

Comment: Do you know of some other way to install RVM? I am just following the main website:  http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: I do not use SuSE and so I cannot comment. I am generally against running shell-script "installers" from web sites because it can be dangerous.

Comment: It might be useful to note that there are more detailed [installation instructions](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) available, which may be helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm following the detailed instructions (which is how I know I need to modify my bash profile in the first place (apparently I missed that requirement in the install docs))  They just tell me the line I need to put in bash, not what to do if that line doesn't work (or if I don't have bash to begin with)